# Is MutationRecord.oldValue something I should be using?

Tags: google-chrome, dom, webkit, mutation-observers

I'm using the latest Google Chrome stable (19.0.1084.56 m) on Windows 7 and experimenting with Mutation observers for the first time. (The project is a user script for a third party website, the server of which I have no access to.)

So it happens that [`MutationRecord`](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#interface-mutationrecord) has a field `oldValue`:

> `record . oldValue`
>
> > The return value depends on `type`. For "`attributes`", it is the value of the changed attribute before the change. For "`characterData`", it is the data of the changed node before the change. For "`childList`", it is null.

So I'm monitoring for changes to the `characterData` but when I get the `MutationRecord` the `oldValue` field is always null.

**Should it be working, is there a possibility I've got something wrong, or is this feature just too bleeding edge to expect to work yet?**

Is there somewhere I can find Google's documentation, bug report, feature request, etc that might declare whether this is implemented or when it might be?

Comment: For anyone who ran into this, I hope you added the `attributeOldValue: true` in the options. It's attribute in singular form. *No error* will be thrown if you put attributesOldValue (WRONG!), you'll just be receiving null for `oldValue`.

Comment: @sirhc: Actually I wasn't watching the attributes but the character data but you were close - I hadn't set the `characterDataOldValue` flag to true! Feel free to submit an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Configure your observer with:

```
observer.observe(container, {
    attributeOldValue : true
});
```

Full API documentation:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: English link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit